# Как хранить данные геометрических фигур в БД (MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

У меня есть 2 полигона на гугл картах. У них есть координаты. Количество их всегда динамично (я могу нарисовать полигон из 3х точек или из 44х точек). Так же я могу, зная эти точки, находить пересечения между ними. Но все это возможно, пока данные фигуры у меня в оперативной памяти.

**А вот и вопрос сложный**: я на клиенте рисую полигон и мне нужно выбрать все записи из таблички в БД (с сохраненными там другими полигонами), которые бы имели пересечение с полигоном, нарисованным на клиенте. Как это можно сделать?
Не выгружать же все полигоны из БД В ОЗУ и искать на клиенте пересечения, ведь записей может быть огромное количество.

Comment: Нужно продумать стратегии оптимизации, например quad-tree, если полигоны небольшие - рассортировать все по областям и сверять пересечения на CPU только в рамках подходящих областей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой класс данных как Geometry.
В вашем случае, лучше использовать MultiPolygon.

Что-то вроде

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0),(5 5,7 5,7 7,5 7, 5 5))';
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (GeomFromText(@g));
```

Тогда вы сможете делать подобные селекты

```
SELECT AsText(g) FROM geom;
```

Более подробную информацию вы можете найти [тут](http://www.rldp.ru/mysql/mysqlpro/spat.htm)

Comment: Да, это решение полностью решает задачу, оказывается MySQL умеет работать с геометрией)
Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Сам недавно начал с ним работать для карт высот, вот и выяснил, что mysql вполне умеет делать это просто